# Extend Backbone model save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is the best way to **extend** the **`model.save` method**?

I need to add new methods to post same data to backend. i.e.: `played` method should request (by POST) to `apiurl/model/:id/played`

e.g.:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.Extend({
   baseUrl: '/games/',
   played: function(){
      this.url = this.baseUrl + this.id + '/played' 
      this.save();
   }
}); 

var game = new Game({id:3234});  //is only an example, instances are created before previuosly
game.played();
```

This way is working but the request is a GET. In addition, it would be perfect if this `save()` did not send all the attributes in the request.

**Adding information:**
As I have to interact with cross domain api, I've extended the sync method in order to work with JSONP. Moreover, I've added some security instructions.

```
//backbone sync
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    //network
    options.timeout = 10000;
    options.dataType = "jsonp";  
    //security
    if(_conf.general.accessToken){
        var ak = _conf.general.accessToken, 
        url = model.url,
        linker = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?':'&';
        model.url = url + linker + 'accessToken=' + ak+'&callback=';    
    }
    //error manager
    var originalError = options.error || function(){};
    options.error = function(res){
        originalError(res.status, $.parseJSON(res.responseText));
    };
    //call original Method 
    Backbone._sync(method, model, options);  
};
```

Comment: Note: The problem here is that `JSONP` is always `GET`, as Martin notes in a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone's save and fetch methods just make calls to the Backbone.sync method, which in turn is just a wrapper for an ajax call. you can pass in ajax parameters using the save function without having to actually extend it. basically ends up being something like this:

```
game.save({attributes you want to save}, {type:'POST', url: 'apiurl/model/:id/played'});
```

You would have to do this every time though so it is probably better practice to extend Backbone.sync for your model.

The Backbone website has a bit of information about what I'm talking about as far as the Backbone sync and save taking ajax options. There are also a few examples I've seen on extending sync but I can't seem to track them down at the moment.

Comment: by the way do mention that `/:id` in the url needs to be replaced by id of the model. Because this would make request to wrong url

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. When I call game.save({...}, {type:'POST'}), the request is always a GET. Maybe my custom sync method is making troubles.

Comment: Make sure the method that is being passed into your backbone.sync is of the correct type. Should be 'create'. In no case should a save ever cause a get request to the server. Should be either POST or PUT. GET is only for fetching. [link](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

Comment: Having red, I noticed that is not possible to use JSONP and POST, Jquery uses GET on JSONP request. That was my problem. I'll have to implement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing insted JSONP. Thanks